# Mulitple JOIN in Spring JpaRepository @Query

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a User entity which has Role. The Role entity has Privileges. My entities look like this :

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @ManyToOne
    public Role role;

    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Role {

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Privilege> privileges;
    
    public Set<Privilege> getPrivileges() {
        return privileges;
    }
    
    public void setPrivileges(Set<Privilege> privileges) {
        this.privileges = privileges;
    }

}
```

```
@Entity
public class Privilege {

    private String action;
    
    public String getAction() {
        return action;
    }
    
    public void setAction(String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

}
```

I would like to load a User with his Role and Privileges of this Role.

I tried to define a method in my JpaRepository with the @Query annotation

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);
    
    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u " +
            "INNER JOIN u.role r " +
            "INNER JOIN r.privileges p " +
            "WHERE u.id = ?1")
    Optional<User> findByIdWithRoleAndPrivileges(Long id);

}
```

My User is loaded with his Role object, but not With the Privileges of the Role.
Any idea on what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: try `@OneToMany private Set<Privilege> privileges;` in class Role

Comment: @MarcStroebel the problem persist. Anyway, since a privileges can be on multiple roles, i don't think I can make it `@OneToMany`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default most associations are fetched lazily. To eagerly fetch the many-to-many Role-Privilege association change your query to:

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u " +
        "INNER JOIN FETCH u.role r " +
        "INNER JOIN FETCH r.privileges p " +
        "WHERE u.id = ?1")
```

The 'JOIN FETCH' is what causes JPA/Hibernate to eagerly fetch the associated entities.